# C++ Awesomium | Проблема с кнопками из за потоков

Tags: c++, awesomium

Есть у меня игра в которую я хотел бы внедрить браузер через Awesomium.
Но тут возникла проблема.
Нажатие клавиш я получаю через хук wndproc а его как я понимаю вызывает поток игры.
А сам Awesomium инициализирован, работает и принадлежит потоку который я создаю в DLL (которую инжектом запихиваю в игру).
И тут появился трабл:

`view->InjectKeyboardEvent(WebKeyboardEvent(mesage, wParam, lParam));`

Если вызвать напрямую InjectKeyboardEvent из WndProc то будет краш так как разные потоки.
А решение которое мне пришло в голову (с переменными) хоть и работает но нужно долго жать кнопку чтобы оно сработало.